# Javascript variable issue with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-audio-api

I am trying to use some javascript with my django code but have a small issue calling functions from the second js file.

I am using code from here https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

I took the html file Matt made and removed the header and created a django template and then put the javascript files with my other static files. Those files (twitter bootstrap) all work fine.

If I open the sheet it loads fine with the record and stop buttons available. If you press them they are recorded in the log but any function that should be called in the recorderWorker.js is ignored. So I can not save the file or see it.

As far as I can tell it never calls the second javascript file. If I put alert boxes in the recorderWorker.js nothing happens but they work in the Recorder.js.

```
var WORKER_PATH = 'recorderWorker.js';
var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
```

I know it is not a problem with the code since I tested it using another Python webserver (SimpleHTTPServer) and it works great.

I have made no changes to the js files and only create this template for the html.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Live input record and playback</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    ul { list-style: none; }
    #recordingslist audio { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  </style>
</head>
```

And then the html file

```
{% extends "base_record.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Recorder.js simple WAV export example</h1>

  <p>Make sure you are using a recent version of Google Chrome, at the moment this only works with Google Chrome Canary.</p>
  <p>Also before you enable microphone input either plug in headphones or turn the volume down if you want to avoid ear splitting feedback!</p>

  <button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>

  <h2>Recordings</h2>
  <ul id="recordingslist"></ul>

  <h2>Log</h2>
  <pre id="log"></pre>

  <script>
  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  var audio_context;
  var recorder;

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.');

    input.connect(audio_context.destination);
    __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input);
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
  }

  function startRecording(button) {
    //  alert("start recording")
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {
    //  alert("Stopped recording")
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Stopped recording.');

    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();

    recorder.clear();
  }

  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        alert("download link")
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
    });
  }

  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;
      __log('Audio context set up.');
      __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
  };
  </script>

{% endblock %}

      <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/recorder.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my settings.py

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static"
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/kevin/Programming/accent/static/',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue where `recorderWorker.js` was not being accessed. However, the problem was solved when I did the following:

```
'static/filename/recorderWorker.js'
```

Note: Assuming that your JS file is located in the folder 'filename' which is in the static folder.

As far as Django is concerned, it looks for static files like JS files into the static folder, since you did not specify the path it did not load the file.